# Set default value for relation in Laravel model based on another relation's value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am querying for a `Food` record and its relationships the following way, setting a default value for one of the relation:

```
$this->foodModel->with(['mainImage', 'category'])->find($foodId);
```

##### `App\Models\Food`

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\FoodCategory', 'food_categ_id');
}

public function mainImage() 
{
    $placeholderUrl = asset('images/placeholders/food.jpg');
    
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Media', 'parentable')
        ->where('primary', 1)
        ->withDefault([
            'url' => $placeholderUrl
        ]);
}
```

But now I want to set the default value according to the `Food`'s category relation for that specific record and I'm not sure how to access the data.

```
public function mainImage() 
{
    $placeholderUrl = asset('images/placeholders/food-categories/' . $category->name . '.jpg') // IS IT POSSIBLE?

    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Media', 'parentable')
        ->where('primary', 1)
        ->withDefault([
            'url' => $placeholderUrl
        ]);
}
```

Comment: I mean... can't you pass an optional parameter on the function like `public function mainImage(string $categoryName = 'default')` or anything similar? This is basic PHP, I am not sure what you want to do. Where si `$category` coming from? It is not defined

Comment: @matiaslauriti `mainImage` is executed by [Eqloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent)'s "eager loading" which means nothing you expect in that function will be passed as a parameter. That being said, the OP is utilising "eager loading" which means that each relation is handled as a seperate SQL query meaning the model has to be first populated before the subquery can be executed. I think the issue here is the order of which you're eager loading your relations (that being said, it wouldnt be a good soltuon to rely on the order - consider normalising this data?)

Comment: Also, your syntax is incorrect, it should be `$this->category->name`... If changing the order doesn't work, you could maybe try initiating the category subquery with `$this->category()->first()->name` but I'm yet to spin up an env to test any of this theory

Comment: @Jaquarh It doesn't make any difference what I load first. `$this->category()->first()->name` gives me the first category in the database but I want to retrieve the category for that specific food (check my first query in the question)

Comment: Given the context of eager loading, it was worth a try. You need to look at normalising your data or moving the relation into the category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to add mainImage into FoodCategory model too and to set default image for each categories?

**App\Models\FoodCategory**

```
public function mainImage() 
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Media', 'parentable')->where('primary', 1)->withDefault(function (Media $media, FoodCategory $category) {
        $media->url = asset('images/placeholders/food-categories/' . $category->name . '.jpg');
    });
}
```

and then into Food model to have Attribute **image** like this:

**App\Models\Food**

```
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['image'];

public function image(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn () => $this->mainImage ?? $this->category->mainImage
    );
}

public function mainImage()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Media', 'parentable')->where('primary', 1);
}
```

and you need to add **category.mainImage** for lazy loading too

```
$this->foodModel->with(['mainImage', 'category', 'category.mainImage'])->find($foodId);
```

If the food has mainImage the image and mainImage will be the same:

[image]

But if the foot does not have mainImage, image will contain the mainImage from the category

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Dr. Reba Dicki",
  "food_categ_id": 1,
  "image": {
    "id": 16,
    "parentable_id": "3",
    "parentable_type": "App\\Models\\Food",
    "primary": 1,
    "url": "https://www.kirlin.com/et-consectetur-aliquam-deserunt-fugit-aut-vel-voluptate"
  },
  "main_image": {
    "id": 16,
    "parentable_id": "3",
    "parentable_type": "App\\Models\\Food",
    "primary": 1,
    "url": "https://www.kirlin.com/et-consectetur-aliquam-deserunt-fugit-aut-vel-voluptate"
  },
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Christophe Hansen"
  }
}
```

... without primary **Food** media

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "Julie Smitham",
  "food_categ_id": 5,
  "image": {
    "id": 5,
    "parentable_id": "5",
    "parentable_type": "App\\Models\\FoodCategory",
    "primary": 1,
    "url": "http://www.padberg.info/et-ab-numquam-harum-ut-aut-doloribus.html"
  },
  "main_image": null,
  "category": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Columbus Krajcik",
    "main_image": {
      "id": 5,
      "parentable_id": "5",
      "parentable_type": "App\\Models\\FoodCategory",
      "primary": 1,
      "url": "http://www.padberg.info/et-ab-numquam-harum-ut-aut-doloribus.html"
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

There is a way **withDefault** but I'm not prefer this because will make a db query for each:

Update only **Food** model and **mainImage** to be:

```
public function mainImage()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\Media', 'parentable')
        ->where('primary', 1)
        ->withDefault(function (Media $media, Food $food) {
            $meda = $media->where([
                'parentable_type' => FoodCategory::class,
                'parentable_id' => $food->food_categ_id,
                'primary' => true,
            ])->first();

            if (!$meda) {
                $meda = new Media();
                $meda->url = asset('images/placeholders/food.jpg');
            }

            return $meda;
        });
}
```

with **Food** media

```
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Dr. Reba Dicki",
  "food_categ_id": 1,
  "main_image": {
    "id": 16,
    "parentable_id": "3",
    "parentable_type": "App\\Models\\Food",
    "primary": 1,
    "url": "https://www.kirlin.com/et-consectetur-aliquam-deserunt-fugit-aut-vel-voluptate"
  },
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Christophe Hansen"
  }
}
```

without **Food** media, but with **FoodCategory** media

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "Julie Smitham",
  "food_categ_id": 5,
  "main_image": {
    "id": 5,
    "parentable_id": "5",
    "parentable_type": "App\\Models\\FoodCategory",
    "primary": 1,
    "url": "http://www.padberg.info/et-ab-numquam-harum-ut-aut-doloribus.html"
  },
  "category": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Columbus Krajcik"
  }
}
```

without **Food** and **FoodCategory** media

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "name": "Clovis Koepp",
  "food_categ_id": 4,
  "main_image": {
    "url": "http://localhost/images/placeholders/food.jpg"
  },
  "category": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Bernita Kuhn"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

For **Laravel** < 9, you need to use [eloquent mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

**App\Models\Food**

```
public function getImageAttribute()
{
    return $this->mainImage ?? $this->category->mainImage;
}
```

Comment: Please don't [upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Use the **Edit** button and replace the screenshots with the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the syntax `get: fn () => $this->mainImage ?? $this->category->mainImage` is not available for Laravel 8.X. Can you update with an alternative? Where can I find it in docs?